# How to create the odom --> base_link transform in gmapping

Tags: navigation, ros-indigo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

We are trying to run gmapping using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 . The problem we are encountering is that the transform between "odom" and "base frame" is not created correctly. Even though we think it should exist since the transform is visible when echoing rostopic. Should the way we are launching gmapping work or is the problem that the robot is not publishing the transforms correctly? Also how do we create the transform between odom and base_link.

running:

> rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree

yields the following result:

[link to tf_tree](https://ibb.co/mymHVf)

As you can see the link between odom and base_link is missing

however when we run

> rostopic echo cvc/tf

The transform between odom and base_link is visible

```
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1539863401
        nsecs: 756178000
      frame_id: odom
    child_frame_id: base_link
    transform: 
      translation: 
        <omitted to save space
      rotation: 
        <omitted to save space>
```

We are using the following launch file:

```
<launch>
  <param name="robot_description"
    textfile="/home/pd/vmc/Thesis_tools/SLAM_launch/gmapping/charm.urdf" /> 

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher"
    type="robot_state_publisher" /> 

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_laser" args="0.23 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_link laser_frame 100" />

  <node name="gmapper" pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" args=""  output="screen">
    <param name="scan_frame" value="cvc/scan"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_frame" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
  </node>
  
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" required="true"
      args="-d gmapping.rviz" />

</launch>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306155/how-to-create-the-odom---%3E-base_link-transform-in-gmapping/) by [sberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/38092/sberg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think your issue comes from `base_link->odom` but from `laser_frame->base_link` and since there is an issue with `base_link`, the link with odom isn't created.

From the [gmapping wiki, section 4.1.5 : Required tf transforms](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping)  :

> the frame attached to incoming scans
> → base_link
>
> usually a fixed value, broadcast periodically by a
> robot_state_publisher, or a tf
> static_transform_publisher.

In your launch file you have `robot_state_publisher` **AND** `static_transform_publisher` so I'm pretty sure you redifine a new parent to the `laser_frame` which often leads to that kind of error in the tf tree. I would suggest to get rid of the `static_transform_publisher`, if your `URDF` is correctly made with the laser frame inside that should work fine.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/38092/sberg/) on 2018-10-19**:
Okay thank you we solved it by removing the `robot_state_publisher` however then the robot model is no longer visible in Rviz. We tried removing both of them and removing `static_transform_publisher` resulted in nothing working.
Where is the documentation on linking sensors to the robot model?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-19**:
Normally you have a `static_transform_publisher` to create a frame so that ROS can link your sensor if it's not represented already in the `URDF`. `robot_state_publisher` already do that if you have it in the URDF so you should remove the `static_transform` instead of `robot_state_publisher`.

**Comment by [sberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/38092/sberg/) on 2018-10-19**:
Thanks
Yes that is what we are trying to do but failing when using the `robot_state_publisher`. We think that the problem is that we do not have the sensor correctly repsresented in the `URDF`-file
The error we are getting is `Fixed frame [map] does not exist` even though the `tf_tree` looks correct

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-19**:
Can you show the tf tree with `robot_state_publisher` please ? Also are you only launching the launch file from the question ? You miss providing the `odometry` information (usually `odom` comes from the `mobile_base` if it's a real robot or `Gazebo` if simulation)

**Comment by [sberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/38092/sberg/) on 2018-10-19**:
Turns out we had named one of the variables wrong in the URDF file. Still kind of strange that the `tf_tree` looked good.

Also a big thank you for your time!